# Sudden 404 Errors in Next.js Website: Seeking Troubleshooting Guidance

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, next.js

Not sure what happened to be honest. The website was working perfectly but then I ran into an issue where I am getting the below errors in the console it is saying 404, I checked the path on the server and all good, the path of the files are exactly located in the .next build folder! The project is built using NextJS framework, not sure if anyone has passed through the same issue, kindly help please!

[image: The above image shows that 404 error for the links, but I do have the path on the server]

Comment: `.next` or `_next`? small typo?

Comment: @clay doesn't look like it is the issue, it is true that I have .next build on server and it is targeting _next on the website, but I have the same locally and it is working ... So I think it is a different issue...